# JQuery Flexigrid: How to get property sortname, sortorder,using javascript？

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flexigrid

Can anyone tell me how to get the flexigrid property value inside the javascript method? For example, `sortname`, `sortorder`? Something like:

```
var sortname = ptable.sortname,
var sortorder = ptable.sortorder,
```

I want to export data to excel,so I could not use the way like

```
refresh: $("#ptable").flexOptions({ params : params}).flexReload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately，I resolve this problem.I add codes in flexigrid.js like this:

```
    $.fn.flexGetParams = function (p) {
    var p, params;
    this.each(function () {
        if (this.grid) p = this.p;
    });
    params = {
        page: p.newp,
        rp: p.rp,
        sortname: p.sortname,
        sortorder: p.sortorder,
        qtype: p.qtype,
        query: p.query
    };

    return params;
}
```

I reference this link:http://www.cnblogs.com/nonkicat/p/4031109.html.So I can invoking like this way:var params = $("#flex1").flexGetParams();